# IIS ASP.NET website connect to SQL Server using individual Windows user credentials

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

My web site uses Windows authentication and the connection string looks like this:

```
<add name="MyConnString"
     connectionString="Server=MyServer;Database=MyDb;Integrated Security=true"  />
```

When I run it on my dev box the web site knows me as my windows login and so does the database. However when I publish the web site to our test server the database refuses connection saying:

> Login failed for user...

and it has the domain and name of the web server so it looks like this:

> Login failed for user MyDomain\Myserver$

Apparently it isn't trying to connect to the database using my windows login. The web site Windows auth is returning my correct windows login.

I admit I have never used a conn string like this before I always us a specific SQL Server login and every one comes in under those credentials, but I'm being asked to do it this way. So the goal would be to grant every users windows login access to this database.

Comment: The identity of the user accessing the site is not passed through to SQL server via ASP.NET. That's just not how it works. When you use integrated security, the identity used to authenticate with SQL Server is the identity that the application pool runs as. You should therefore give the account that your app pool run as permission to your SQL Server, everything it needs to do its job. Whether an end user is allowed to do something or not should be controlled by your application, rather than permissions in SQL Server.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I have tried tweaking the app pool but none of the settings work the way we are trying to get it to work.. ty for your help

Comment: If you are currently using IIS Express to run it on your dev box, you should get a more realistic environment by using IIS.

Comment: I did such thing using *impersonation* and *Basic Authentication*

Comment: Did you set that under the advanced opitons in the app pool settings?

Comment: I strongly caution you to avoid impersonation and basic authentication. Impersonation can cause all sorts of issues and [Microsoft cautions against it](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/AvoidUsingImpersonationInASPNET.aspx). And basic authentication won't lead to a good user experience. Design your app properly: have it be responsible for the connection to the database and managing permissions.

Comment: you could try to use the Windows authentication:`<add name="windowsConnection" connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=databasename; Trusted_Connection=True;" />`  in Asp.net.If you are using windows authentication to connect to the Server DB, you need to set "Trusted_Connection=True;" if you are using SQL server authentication, you need to declare User "Id=myUsername; Password=myPassword;".`<add name="Sqlserverconnection" connectionstring="server=localhost; Database=databasename;uid=db; password=123 "/>`